# I'm trying to predict probability of X_test and getting 2 values in an array. I need to compare those 2 values and make it 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, sklearn-pandas

**I'm trying to predict probability of X_test and getting 2 values in an array. I need to compare those 2 values and make it 1.**

when I write code

```
y_pred = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)
y_pred
```

It gives output like

```
array([[0.5, 0.5],
       [0.6, 0.4],
       [0.7, 0.3],
       ...,
       [0.5, 0.5],
       [0.4, 0.6],
       [0.3, 0.7]])
```

**We know that if values if >= 0.5 then it's and 1 and if it's less than 0.5 it's 0**

I converted the above array into pandas using below code

```
proba = pd.DataFrame(proba)
proba.columns = [['pred_0', 'pred_1']]
proba.head()
```

And output is

```
    pred_0  pred_1
0   0.5     0.5
1   0.6     0.4
2   0.7     0.3
3   0.4     0.6
4   0.3     0.7
```

How to iterate the above rows and write a condition that if row value of column 1 is greater than equal to 0.5 with row value of 2, then it's 1 and if row value of column 1 is less than 0.5 when compared to row value of column 2.

For example, by seeing the above data frame the output must be

```
  output
0 0
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
```

Comment: "column 1 is less than 0.5 when compared to row value of column 2" How are you comparing "pred_0" and "pred_1"?

Comment: I'm trying to iterate rows of two columns and want to compare them. If column1, 1st-row value is greater than column2, 2nd-row value then it should return 1 or else 0

Comment: Compare 1st row (0.5) with 1st row (0.5) it should return 1. Similarly compare 2nd row (0.6) with 2 row (0.4) it should return 1. Condition is if row 1 column 1 value >= row 1 column 2 value, it should return 1 or else 0.

Comment: Compare 0.5 with 0.5, it should return 0. Compare 0.6 with 0.4 it should return 1 etc in a new column. The main condition is if column 1 row 1 value >= column 2 row 1 value, it should return 1 or else 0

Comment: So the values in expected output for idx 3 and 4 are incorrect?

Comment: yes, just compare row values with the given condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just map your initial array without converting it to a Pandas Dataframe so that it returns True when the first value of every subarray is >= 0.5 and if not it returns False. And finally, convert it to int:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0.5, 0.5], [0.6, 0.4], [0.3, 0.7]])
>>> a
array([[0.5, 0.5],
       [0.6, 0.4],
       [0.3, 0.7]])
>>> result = map(lambda x:int(x[0] >= 0.5), a)
>>> print(list(result))
[1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the two columns to create a boolean index then convert to `int` using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype):

Option 1:

```
df['output'] = (df['pred_0'] >= df['pred_1']).astype(int)
```

Option 2:

```
df['output'] = df['pred_0'].ge(df['pred_1']).astype(int)
```

---

Or via [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

Option 3:

```
df['output'] = np.where(df['pred_0'] >= df['pred_1'], 1, 0)
```

Option 4:

```
df['output'] = np.where(df['pred_0'].ge(df['pred_1']), 1, 0)
```

```
   pred_0  pred_1  output
0     0.5     0.5       1
1     0.6     0.4       1
2     0.7     0.3       1
3     0.4     0.6       0
4     0.3     0.7       0
```